# maraidb CTE, how to reuse selected order?

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression

I haev a query where I have a CTE that selects some rows in a specfic order, and I want to use that same order for my main data set Im returning:

```sql
WITH selector (id) AS (SELECT id FROM ..... ORDER BY something)
SELECT ...
FROM users u
JOIN selector s ON s.id = u.id
ORDER BY FIELD(u.id, (SELECT id FROM selector))
```

but this isn't valid syntax in the last ORDER BY FIELD statement as the sub query returns more than one row, is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Looking at your example, you shouldn't need to use FIELD at all. Perhaps you are using a simpler example of something more complex you want to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) needs a list of values and not the results of a query.

You can use the function  [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) to create a comma separated list of ids returned by the CTE, ordered by your conditions and then the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to join the CTE to the table and sort by its result:

```
WITH selector (ids) AS (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY something) FROM .....)
SELECT ...
FROM users u INNER JOIN selector s 
ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, s.ids)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(u.id, s.ids)
```

Or, use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH selector (id, rn) AS (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) FROM .....)
SELECT ...
FROM users u INNER JOIN selector s 
ON s.id = u.id
ORDER BY s.rn
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed the second half of your answer and just wrote exactly the same answer using `ROW_NUMBER()` (a much better solution IMO). I thought I was having double vision and then I realised it was part of your answer...